# Spring Boot Log4j2 Custom Hybrid Log Layout - Mix of Pattern Layout and JSON Layout

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I would like to know how I print my application logs to console in a specific format of my choice.

Our ELK stack's FileBeat daemon is configured to recognise only those Kubernetes pod logs that are in this pattern - `appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{ISO8601} - %-5level: %msg%n`

This is done so as to keep track of all incoming requests and some attributes of responses. Generally `msg` part in above pattern contains http requests and responses. Now, I built a new Microservice in Spring Boot that does not have any http interactions. It consumes messages from Kafka and processes them. So, the logs would be mostly application log statements and exceptions.

If I follow the above pattern, my exceptions will be logged as strings and I cannot index logs and filter based on any keys in Kibana. To solve this problem, I need to log msg as JSON just like in JSON layout of log4j2.

I tried putting the following in log4j2.properties file. I am getting a cool json for each log statement but filebeat won't pick this up since it is configured to pick only logs in previously specified format.

```
log4j2.appender.console.json.type = JsonTemplateLayout
log4j2.appender.console.json.eventTemplateUri = classpath:EcsLayout.json
```

Could anyone help me arrive at a solution where I can log in the acceptable format only which the `msg` part is a json that looks like following.

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2017-05-25T19:56:23.370Z",
  "ecs.version": "1.2.0",
  "log.level": "ERROR",
  "message": "Hello, error!",
  "process.thread.name": "main",
  "log.logger": "org.apache.logging.log4j.JsonTemplateLayoutDemo",
  "error.type": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
  "error.message": "test",
  "error.stack_trace": "java.lang.RuntimeException: test\n\tat org.apache.logging.log4j.JsonTemplateLayoutDemo.main(JsonTemplateLayoutDemo.java:11)\n"
}
```

In essence, my log statement should be

```
2022-11-23T15:50:05,802 - ERROR : {"@timestamp":"2017-05-25T19:56:23.370Z","ecs.version":"1.2.0","log.level":"ERROR","message":"Hello, error!","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"org.apache.logging.log4j.JsonTemplateLayoutDemo","error.type":"java.lang.RuntimeException","error.message":"test","error.stack_trace":"java.lang.RuntimeException: test\n\tat org.apache.logging.log4j.JsonTemplateLayoutDemo.main(JsonTemplateLayoutDemo.java:11)\n"}
```

I tried using Pattern Layout and JSON Layout. But I am expecting a Custom Layout that mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `logback-classic` dependency for that.
First add this dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then add this logger to `logback.xml`

```
<appender name="json" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
        <jsonFormatter
            class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
            <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
        </jsonFormatter>
        <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampFormat>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="jsonLogger" level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="json" />
</logger>
```

After that, you can call it like this:

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("jsonLogger");
logger.info("test message");
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Pattern Layout with the following pattern in log4j2.properties

`appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{ISO8601} - %level: {"timestamp":"%d{ISO8601}","thread.id":"%T","thread.name":"%t","log.level":"%-5level","log.logger":"%fqcn","message":"%m","error.class_name":"%throwable{short.className}","error.method_name":"%throwable{short.methodName}","error.file_name":"%throwable{short.fileName}","error.line_number":"%throwable{short.lineNumber}","error.message":"%throwable{short.message}","error.localized_message":"%throwable{short.localizedMessage}"}%n`

Reference: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout

Comment: This one worked for me